# Conditional checked on laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'n trying to set checked a checkbox on laravel template depending on a php variable this way

```
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Man" class="input-radio-gender" id="genderOther"  <% echo $consumerInfo['attributes']['gender']=='Man'?'checked':''%>>
```

But its not workig, what I hace to change?

Comment: The "ASP" style tags `<% %>` are no longer in PHP since version 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use laravel [@if](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements) directive here like this

```
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Man" class="input-radio-gender" id="genderOther" 
 @if($consumerInfo['attributes']['gender'] =='Man')
  checked
 @endif
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you use interpolation symbols `{{}}`? Below should work.

```
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Man" class="input-radio-gender" id="genderOther"  {{ $consumerInfo['attributes']['gender']== 'Man'? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added since Laravel 9
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#checked-and-selected)

```
<input type="checkbox"
        name="active"
        value="active"
        @checked(old('active', $user->active)) />
```